# Aligning bmatrix by its border while centered

Tags: horizontal-alignment, matrices

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \newcommand*\Eval[3]{\left.#1\right\rvert_{#2}^{#3}}

    The Matrix is: \\
    \medskip

    $\begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{A}{B} & \frac{C}{D} \\[6pt]
        \frac{E}{F} & \frac{G}{H} 
    \end{bmatrix}$

    $\implies \Eval{\begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{A}{B} & \frac{C}{D} \\[6pt]
        \frac{E}{F} & \frac{G}{H} 
        \end{bmatrix}}{LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT}{}$

    $\implies \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{A}{B} & \frac{C}{D} \\[6pt]
    \frac{E}{F} & \frac{G}{H} 
    \end{bmatrix}$
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I have a few matrices that are centered in my page, with implies arrows in front of them. How do I go about aligning the matrices such that the borders of the matrix line up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you should use an `align*` environment  for that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    The Matrix is:
\end{center}
\begin{align*}
 & \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{A}{B} & \frac{C}{D} \\[6pt]
        \frac{E}{F} & \frac{G}{H}
        \end{bmatrix} \\[1ex]
    \implies & \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{A}{B} & \frac{C}{D} \\[6pt]
        \frac{E}{F} & \frac{G}{H}
        \end{bmatrix} \\[1ex]
        \implies & \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{A}{B} & \frac{C}{D} \\[6pt]
    \frac{E}{F} & \frac{G}{H}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:

Here is a code toadd some text on the right of a matrix while retaining the matrices centered. The width of the tabular column has to be adapted to the real situation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    The Matrix is:
\end{center}
\begin{align*}
 & \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{A}{B} & \frac{C}{D} \\[6pt]
        \frac{E}{F} & \frac{G}{H}
        \end{bmatrix} \\[1ex]
    \implies & \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{A}{B} & \frac{C}{D} \\[6pt]
        \frac{E}{F} & \frac{G}{H}
        \end{bmatrix}\rlap{\quad\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}@{}}LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT\end{tabular}} \\[1ex]
        \implies & \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{A}{B} & \frac{C}{D} \\[6pt]
    \frac{E}{F} & \frac{G}{H}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is alignned, but how do you center the whole alignment to the page?

Comment: An align environment is *internally* alignment at the specified points, but the whole environment is centred. This is more perceptible adding the showframe option of geometry (image updated).

Comment: I updated my MWE, I added the "Eval" command I'm using to draw a bar to the right of the matrix with some text. I didn't think that would have made a difference. Sorry.

Comment: How do you define this `\Eval` command?

Comment: It's updated in my MWE
`\newcommand*\Eval[3]{\left.#1\right\rvert_{#2}^{#3}}`

Comment: It compiles, but the matrices, of course, are no more centred, and the text is typed in math mode, not as text. What exactly are you trying to achieve, ideally?

Comment: Matrices with evaluation bars on the right aligned by their left bracket.

Comment: And the text after the evaluation bar should be  vertically centred w.r.t. the relevant matrix?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: @HighMans: I've added a solution for this case. Is it what you want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76281/discussion-between-highmans-and-bernard).